# How do I select one exact substring but not another from a string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following entries stored in an attribute in mysql:

> BFA.AD
>
> a:11:{i:0;s:6:"BFA.AD";i:1;s:11:"BFA.AD.COPY";i:2;s:6:"BFA.AE";i:3;s:6:"BFA.TC";i:4;s:6:"BFA.FA";i:5;s:6:"BFA.GC";i:6;s:6:"BFA.IL";i:7;s:6:"BFA.IN";i:8;s:6:"BFA.PH";i:9;s:6:"BFA.PR";i:10;s:6:"BFA.TR";}
>
> BFA.AD.COPY
>
> BFA.TR

I am trying to write a case when statement that matches the following conditions:
when a record contains BFA.AD or is exactly BFA.AD, then 1 else 0.

So, with the four records listed above, in order the results should be 1, 1, 0, and 0.

I have tried:

```
case when (select m.meta_value from `ccsadm_frm_item_metas` m where m.item_id = i.id and m.field_id = 1308) like '%BFA.AD%' then 1 else 0 end as 'BFA.AD',
```

which marks both BFA.AD and BFA.AD.COPY as 1.  I have tried using the regular expression `["]\bBFA.AD\b["]`, but that does not seem to work in MySQL.

Comment: Can you take a step back and talk about how this case statement fits within larger query?  You are going down a path that is requiring nest subselects and it is unclear whether this is even necessary without understanding the full query.

Comment: The big picture is this query is flattening a bunch web forms collected in a Wordpress web form so that each form entry is listed as a single record in the result set so that it can be used in a 3rd party reporting system and to import the data into an ERP system via a single data file.

Answer (score 0):

```
case when (select m.meta_value 
            from `ccsadm_frm_item_metas` m 
            where m.item_id = i.id 
            and m.field_id = 1308) 
                like 'BFA.AD' then 1 else 0 
                end as 'BFA_Type',
```

OR

```
case when (select m.meta_value 
            from `ccsadm_frm_item_metas` m 
            where m.item_id = i.id 
            and m.field_id = 1308) 
                like 'BFA.AD' then 1 else 0 
                end as 'BFA.AD',
case when (select m.meta_value 
            from `ccsadm_frm_item_metas` m 
            where m.item_id = i.id 
            and m.field_id = 1308) 
                like 'BFA.AD.COPY' then 1 else 0 
                end as 'BFA.AD.COPY',
```

Comment: Hmm, your second example is where I started, and when the string contains:  a:11:{i:0;s:6:"BFA.AD";i:1;s:11:"BFA.AD.COPY";...
The result is: BFA.AD = 0; BFA.AD.COPY = 0.

Comment: First on will print in "BFA_Type" column a 1 if it is BFA.AD otherwise a 0. Second will have two columns and will be a 1 if satisfied else 0

Comment: If it is one long string both would always be 1... Paste some more strings please in your original post place double quotes around the entire string

Comment: It is a key value pair list.  What's happening here is we have a web form where there is a checklist, and when visitors check off items, the codes get stored in the list.  The order is irrelevant, except that it is consistent... in other words, if the user checks `BFA.AD` and `BFA.AD.COPY`, `BFA.AD` will always appear first in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that works for what I need in this specific case:

```
case when (select i.form_id = 193) then case when (select m.meta_value from `ccsadm_frm_item_metas` m where m.item_id = i.id and m.field_id = 1308) regexp 'BFA.AD["]' or (select m.meta_value from `ccsadm_frm_item_metas` m where m.item_id = i.id and m.field_id = 1308) = 'BFA.AD' then 1 else 0 end
```

So, far, it appears to be working.  Thanks for everyone's help, as you got me thinking about some other options I hadn't tried yet.